# MySQL trigger syntax error on insert after with variables

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am trying to track users sales based on the new transactions that come through. The transactions are assigned through our site and not their desktop application. It is giving me a syntax error, but I can't seem to figure out why.

This is my code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS AssignTrans;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `testing_cake3`.`AssignTrans` AFTER INSERT ON `main_1` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      SET @t1 = (SELECT team_id FROM team_assignments WHERE team_assignments.misc_id = NEW.CUSTOMER_ID AND team_assignments.type = 1);
      SET @t2 = (SELECT team_id FROM team_assignments WHERE team_assignments.misc_id = NEW.GROUP_ID AND team_assignments.type = 0);
      IF (@t1) THEN
          INSERT INTO team_trans (team_id, trans_id, type, misc_id) VALUES (@t1, NEW.id, 0, 1 );
      ELSE IF (@t2) THEN
          INSERT INTO team_trans (team_id, trans_id, type, misc_id) VALUES (@t2, NEW.id, 0, 1 );
      END IF;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What is the syntax error that you're given?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

Comment: Is this when you are setting the trigger or when you are running a command that would set it off?

Comment: When I am running the command to create the trigger

Comment: Change `ELSE IF` by `ELSEIF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe answer is CHANGING THE ELSE IF TO ElSEIF